# Adding Ghost Frame to Drake Model

Tags: python, drake

I currently have a URDF that contains a robotic arm without any gripper. I am using pydrake to perform inverse kinematics for the arm but would like to attach a dummy frame to the end in order to constrain the position of the gripper rather than the position of the arm itself. I assume that I should use the function `WeldFrames()` but how can I set up the ghost gripper frame for this use?

Note: I may use multiple types of grippers and would therefore like to do this programmatically instead of changing the URDF directly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have an arm (without a gripper) in urdf, and separate urdfs for the various grippers.  You could weld the gripper to the last link directly in the link coordinates -- [see here for an example](https://github.com/RussTedrake/manipulation/blob/61199b176a9762c01a21c72f32ef33976465d0ba/manipulation/scenarios.py#L106).

If you want to add another frame to that final link, for instance to indicate the mounting plate for the end-effectors, you can add that to the arm's urdf and weld in that frame instead.  [Here is an example of that](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/f718a6a1bbbfbf5b2d00c9fe9d351e2b40b30e5f/manipulation/models/iiwa_description/urdf/iiwa14_no_collision.urdf#L307).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I realized that the gripper urdf was not worth using so I just created a `FixedOffsetFrame()` and used `plant.AddFrame()` to the model instead of merging the gripper urdf.